# return and return undefined in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I read the specification I noticed that there are several kinds of return.

One of them is `return undefined`. This record can be understood because the value of undefined is used by the ECMAScript algorithms. But what does it mean to `return` without an argument? In the specification, I did not see a description of this behavior.

For example: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-putvalue section `6. d. Return.`

Comment: *"A return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the caller. If Expression is omitted, the return value is undefined. Otherwise, the return value is the value of Expression."*

Comment: @KevinB where is from this quote?

Comment: from the link you provided. 13.10

Comment: @KevinB It's true if we are talking about the JS language operator, but it's not about the JS language operator, but about the return ECMAScript.

Comment: It's right there in the spec you are referencing.

Comment: @MaximPro JavaScript and ECMAScript are the same thing! You need to learn a bit more about what the language you are asking about actually is.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-implicit-completion-values

Comment: Are you talking about return statements, or about records (completion values of type "return")?

Comment: @Bergi How do you think `6. d. Return.` in PutValue, what is type of return?

Comment: it is undefined, as defined by the spec. *"A “return” statement without a value in an algorithm step means the same thing as: Return NormalCompletion(undefined)."*

Comment: @KevinB You should post that as an answer. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: All I could find is [the "Algorithm Conventions" chapter](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-algorithm-conventions) which states "*Calls to abstract operations return Completion Records.*", so PutValue being an abstract operation it has to return a completion record which would typically mean one with an undefined value by default.

Comment: my quote was from my most recent link

Comment: @KevinB Oh, right, you had already linked it in the comments. But really, that is the answer that the OP is looking for, you should post it as such!

Comment: @ScottMarcus He is talking about the spec language, the natural language that defines the abstract algorithms in the spec document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usage is explained earlier on in the spec under the [Implicit Completion Values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-implicit-completion-values) section:

> A “return” statement without a value in an algorithm step means the same thing as:
>
> 1. Return [NormalCompletion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-normalcompletion)(**undefined**).

So any time the spec uses a Return statement without a value, you can assume that it is returning undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `undefined` are straightforward: it's the language telling you, "I have no idea".  So for instance if you do this:

```
const a = [17]
a[3] = 42
```

And then try to fetch the value at index 1:

```
a[1]
```

you will get `undefined`.  Think of the system as saying, "Well, you started with a one-element array, and then set the value at index 3, which I know means that you now have length 4, so I can go look at element with index 1.  Oh dear, that hasn't been set.  So I'll just tell you that it's undefined."

There is nothing to enforce that your function have a `return` statement<sup>1</sup>, or that, if it does, you have to supply an actual value.  So if you call a function and capture its return value, there is no guarantee that there is something there to capture.

In this scenario:

```
function foo(x) {console.log(x);}
const result = foo(42);
```

the value of `result` will be `undefined`.  We didn't return anything.  But the same thing is true of this function:

```
function bar(x) {console.log(x); return;}
```

And in this one:

```
function baz(x) {console.log(x); return undefined;}
```

we explicitly return the `undefined` value.

We could even do this:

```
function qux(x) {return console.log(x);}
```

and because `console.log` itself returns `undefined`, so will our function.

These all have exactly the same behavior from the perspective of a user.  I suppose there is some philosophical question about how the `undefined` we receive was generated, but there are no practical difference.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is in contrast to various other languages.  Some require an explicit return, some simply return the value of the last expression evaluated in the function.  Still others distinguish *functions*, which must have a return from callable *procedures*, which don't.  Some have a signal value, something like `undefined` for when nothing is returned, usually `nil` or `null`.  But Javascript's `null` semantics are a bit different from that.

Comment: If you talk about JavaScript you will be right. But open the specification and look for "Return." There will be few such coincidences. And I'm interested in knowing that I should return a `return` without an argument.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  What coincidences?  The specification mentions `Return` in many places.  But this is a specification for those *implementing* the language, not those using it.  It doesn't say anything about when your code should use `return`.  (In my mind, you should explicitly return from *every* function.)

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean to `Return` without an argument, such as in step 6. d. of [PutValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-putvalue)?

It's mostly natural language in the spec, so "Return" just mean "Abort this algorithm and do not run any further steps". If you want to be more thorough with your formalisms:

From the ["Algorithm Conventions" chapter](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-algorithm-conventions) we know that "*Calls to abstract operations return Completion Records.*", and the ["Implicit Completion Values" chapter](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-implicit-completion-values) states "*A “return” statement without a value in an algorithm step means the same thing as:

Return NormalCompletion(`undefined`).*"

Well, they are *implicit* completion values.

Answer (score 0):

**PREFACE:**

Since you seem to be confused as to the relationship between JavaScript and ECMAScript, let me share this passage **[from Wikipedia on JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)**:

> **JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/),**[6] often abbreviated as JS, is a
>   high-level, interpreted programming language. It is a language which
>   is also characterized as dynamic, weakly typed, prototype-based and
>   multi-paradigm.
>
> Alongside HTML and CSS, JavaScript is one of the three core
>   technologies of the World Wide Web.[citation needed] It is used to
>   make dynamic webpages interactive and provide online programs,
>   including video games. The majority of websites employ it[citation
>   needed], and all modern web browsers support it without the need for
>   plug-ins by means of a built-in JavaScript engine. Each of the many
>   JavaScript engines represent a different implementation of JavaScript,
>   **all based on the ECMAScript specification**, with some engines not
>   supporting the spec fully, and with many engines supporting additional
>   features beyond ECMA.

So, while some browsers may not fully support the most recent specification (i.e. Chrome 10 isn't going to be compliant with ES2017). And some supporting additional features, any client that is "standards compliant" (and that is all modern main-stream clients) have a runtime that processes ECMAScript.

In short, when you write JavaScript in a standards-compliant client, you are writing ECMAScript.

---

There is only one kind of `return`. If you just `return` from a function without specifying a value, the function returns `undefined`. If you do specify a value, then that is what is returned.

EXAMPLES:

```js
function returnUndefined(){
  return; // Notice we're not specifying anything to return
}

console.log(returnUndefined()); // undefined

function returnUndefined2(){
  // Here, we are explicitly returning undefined, although no one actually does this
  // because if that's what you want, just use plain old return
  return undefined; 
}

console.log(returnUndefined2()); // undefined

function returnSomething(){
  return "Summer"; // Here, we are explicitly returning a meaningful value
}

console.log(returnSomething()); // "Summer"
```

Comment: Yes, if we talk about what happens if you write return on JS. But it's about ECMAScript and him "returns"

Comment: @MaximPro JavaScript is ECMAScript! This is the correct answer.

Comment: @MaximPro ECMAScript is the name of a standardized scripting language. That language is then "implemented" in various software clients, like Node.js and web browsers. "JavaScript" is one of those implementations. `JavaScript === ECMAScript`.

Comment: ECMAScript algorithms are not written by JavaScript. From this we can conclude that the ECMAScript algorithms are written in a different language. Accordingly, the return is not from JS.

Comment: @MaximPro That statement is completely inaccurate. No matter what language the JavaScript runtime is written in (there is no specification that requires any particular language), the runtime **must** by definition execute exactly the same in any implementation that supports it.

Comment: Have you seen the link to PutValue? These lines of this function are executed by the language that implements ECMAScript. Accordingly, Return in this algorithm is not the same as return on JS.
You generally write me an example on JS, although I'm not asking you about it, I'm asking specifically about the lines of the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: @MaximPro Let me try it this way. **ECMAScript is a *"specification"*, not software**. It is created by the **E**uropean **C**omputer **M**anufacturer's **A**ssociation. The specification is essentially an instruction manual for actual software vendors to take and build a runtime environment from. Some vendors may choose to write that runtime in C, others may Choose Java - that's not important and ECMA does not stipulate anything at all about the language used to build the runtime or anything else about its construction (continued)...

Comment: Wow, while I'm off typing my screed, another Scott turns his brief comment into another screed.  I do wonder, though, exactly which browsers will be compatible with ES2107.  I'm hoping we've moved to more exciting technologies by then!

Comment: @MaximPro (continued...) What the software vendor must do is follow the instruction manual (the specification) in its abstract design. The specification will say that when this or that keyword is used, here's how to logically process it. So, the rules for handling `return` may be implemented at a low level by any language at all, but the result must follow what the spec. says. The moral to the story is that the implementation doesn't matter, only the spec. does.

Comment: @ScottSauyet LOL - - Wishful thinking on my part, I guess! ;)

Comment: I'd say that `JavaScript === ECMAScript` is a little overstated, especially in light of Oracle's recent moves.  Instead, "There are various implementations of the ECMAScript standard written with names such as JavaScript and JScript.  For historical reasons, these often are collectively called 'JavaScript'."

Comment: @ScottSauyet Agreed. But, I think for the purposes of this thread, I'll leave it as is.